# If he got the job, he would be very happy now

Tags: conditionals, modal-verbs, perfect-aspect, would

Consider this, please:

Person A: My brother was supposed to appear for an interview at 8am, and now it's 10. **I don't know if he got the job or not**. But one thing is for sure,

1. If he **got** the job, he **would** be very happy now.
2. If he **got** the job, I **would** assume he is very happy now.
3. If he **had got(ten)** the job, he **would** be very happy now.
4. If he **had got(ten)** the job, I **would** assume he is very happy now.

Are these sentences all correct?

Comment: In the second sentence, you want to focus on the state of happiness. None of yours are idiomatic where I am. You would either say "if he *did get* the job, he is very happy now" or "if he *has gotten* the job, he is very happy now*. You don't want the second *would* or the *I assume* when you lead in with "one thing is for sure".

Comment: All work for me, though 3 and 4 imply an uncertain consequence that is not given (*If he'd got the job he would (have) phone(d) me...(why hasn't he?*)).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my opinion: When I read your sentences (type 2 conditional and more likely be type 3 conditional sentences), the way I understand is that your brother failed the job interview. However, in reality, you have not known the result just yet. In this case, I feel that you should use the type 1 conditional sentence to describe what will happen if your brother passes the interview.

> If he gets the job, he will be very happy.

Comment: That would be true if the interview had not yet happened, but if it _has_ already happened I would say "If he has got the job, he will/must be very happy now."

Answer (score 1):

I find all of these sentences to be a bit awkward and ambiguous.

Here are sentences that I believe communicate the potential meanings better:

If my brother had gotten the job, he would have been happy.

If my brother got the job, he will be happy.

If my brother were to have gotten the job, he would have been happy.